# MySql grouping multile fields

Tags: mysql

I need to group some data from my DB, say if my data is

```
url, siteId
abc, 1
abc, 1
abc, 2
abc, 2
abc, 2
```

I need to count the number of URL's at each site. I tried using `GROUP BY url` and `SELECT *, COUNT(url) as urlCount`, however, that grouped all 5 together. Is this possible using mysql alone or would I need some PHP to format that data?

Comment: You want to **GROUP BY url** then it will show only 1 row as **abc** is the only value of the **url** column. Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `siteid`and not by `url`

```
select siteid, count(distinct url) as urlCount
from your_table
group by siteid
```

If you use `distinct` then you will get the count of unique urls.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I tried that sql before, but without the `distinct`, thanks! I'll accept this soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT siteId, COUNT(url) AS urlCount
FROM tablename
GROUP BY siteId
```

As you wrote, *I need to count the number of URL's **at each site***, for sql query you would write this as **GROUP BY siteId**.